# Dependency Injection/SOLID Worries

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, solid-principles

I have a Web API application written in C#. I am trying to ensure the design adheres to SOLID principles. As such I am using Unity to inject dependencies into my controllers. However I want to get the actions performed by the controllers out of the controllers themselves, so they essentially just call methods on other (often static) objects. For instance:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ISomeCrossCuttingInterface _instance;
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public MyController(ISomeCrossCuttingInterface someInterface, ILog log)
    {
        _instance = someInterface;
        _log = log;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("MyAction")]
    public RequestResponse MyAction(MyActionData actionData)
    {
        try
        {
            return MyActionUser(actionData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error("MyAction error", ex);
        }
        return ...;
    }

    private RequestResponse MyActionUser(MyActionData actionData)
    {
        var responseObj = StaticClass.SomeMethod(_instance, actionData);
        var responseObj2 = StaticClass2.SomeMethod(_instance, responseObj2);
        return CreateMyActionResponse(responseObj2);
    }

    private RequestResponse CreateMyActionResponse(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I am experiencing some angst over is whether the objects used to perform the work (eg. StaticClass and StaticClass2 above) should actually be injected. Currently they aren't. The objects that have been injected are those that are related to cross cutting concerns such as logging or data access, or that are used by more than one controller. So why am I not injecting the objects that perform the work? I am thinking that these 'internal' objects are only used to perform the specific work related to one controller. That is, the controllers functionality has essentially been broken down into objects with a single responsiblity, with each controller having it's own unique set of objects that do whatever the controller needs to do. However is this a bad design? Should all objects be injected regardless? Any input really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using SOLID principles is widely accepted that it will make your code more maintainable, testable and flexible. If you use some of these principles, it's better than not using any.

Try to think about what could happen if you want to change your static class somehow. Can you be confident that the change won't break one of your controllers? You can have unit tests for your static class, and some for your controller, but you'd need integration tests to check that they work together. If you inject your static class instead, then you could easily make unit tests for checking that the method was called, returns the correct result, etc.

Also you don't really want your controller to be doing this logic, it should be nice and lean, so put everything into a service and let the service handle the logic, calling the repository etc. Then inject the service into the controller.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a better approach, my current code doesn't smell right(!). The service would need to be setup in my Unity config as follows: container.RegisterType<ILoginService, LoginService>(). This would let unity know what type to create for this dependency. What I need to find out then is how I pass the dependencies for the LoginService to it.

Comment: You can make it easier for yourself by using `container.RegisterTypes` instead, which would scan a set of assemblies for classes that implement your interfaces. You can use a convention so that if there is a `LoginService` that implements an `ILoginService` then that's the type that will automatically be resolved through injection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you should NOT inject are stable, 3rd party libraries that you know for sure won't change and don't need Testability, Maintainability, Parallel Development, Extensibility or Late Binding.

If the `StaticClass` actually contains the logic of `MyController` why not include it's methods as part of `StaticClass`? Otherwise, it must be doing something else, on another level (different concern).

I'm sure you already have this excellent resource on your shelf, but just to be sure, I'll put a link here:
[Dependency Injection in .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) (Mark Seemann).

*From my own personal experience*: If you're actually making a small application, just for the fun of it and which you'll probably throw out when it's done, just have fun with it. Use Dependency Injection here and there, write some Unit Test to see how it feels and get the hang of it. You can't make if perfect. 
For example, can you easily change between a Console and WPF/WinForms application? What would need to change? How easily can you swap the modules between the two applications? Try writing different `ILog` implementations. Maybe you want your logs on your console, maybe you want them in some GUI, txt or xml file. How easy is to change your code? Loosely-coupled code is the whole point and the Dependency Injection pattern helps here.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. To illustrate the use of the static classes, I have a LoginController that uses a static class to validate the login (get the data from the repository and check the password) and a second static class to create a session (also saved in the repository as this application uses REST).

Comment: I have modified my design, thanks for your input. Thanks for the book recommendation  too, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well.

You seem to think you will want to mock your repository. In a similar manner you might want to inject other behaviours for your StaticClass as well. But if the behaviour is fixed then keep it as is.

If you make everything injectable you will find it leads to code bloat. So my advice is not to use inversion of control to adhare to SOLID pronciples, but to use it to cover actual testing scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. I actually am mocking my repository as this is for an application that will run in the cloud (probably on AWS). Just to initially piece everything together I have mocked the repository.